# Akka cluster behavior after bringing down one node

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I'm using Akka 2.6 and seeing some weird behavior
Setup:
Node0
Node1
Node2

On starting the cluster, I can see the welcome message from
Node0-Node1
Node0-Node2

When I gave some work, it was getting distributed across all three nodes. So everything was working as expected

Now to test out something, I brought down Node2 and started getting a "Leader can currently not perform its duties, reachability status" warning. Node0 and Node1 were still doing their work without any issues.

Now when I brought back Node2, I got the provisioner registered message BUT, if the work is taken by Node0 or Node1, it was not shared with Node2. The same work was getting shared by all three nodes when I tested before bringing down Node2.

Also, if Node2 is taking some work, it is getting distributed across all three nodes. So basically Node1 or Node2 are not giving any work to Node3.

Can someone help me with this.. I'm not able to understand why this is happening and how to fix this. I'm using Java 17 if it helps.

Comment: Are you running with the split brain resolver (assuming that you're forcefully stopping Node2 rather than letting it leave gracefully)?  Are you using cluster sharing or some other technique for distributing work?

Comment: Agreed: understanding how you are sharing work will be important to understand/debug. Also, the actual logs from startup and any additional cluster logging messages would help. "Provisioner registered" isn't something I recognize. And "leader can't perform their duties" would indicate a lack of consensus.

Comment: Give more information to understand what you are doing, as Levi and David said which technique you used for distribute work, and proper logs